# Android alarm sound doesn't work first time on real device

Tags: android

I have developed an android app which includes an `AlarmReceiver` with an optional reminder sound (0.5sec mp3 resource via `MediaPlayer`).

The `AlarmReceiver` works fine. But the reminder sound exhibits erratic behavior while playing on real devices.

At first attempt on a real device it fails to work, but starts to work fine after it.

I tried uninstalling the application and deleting its data but still result is same.

Any ideas appreciated.`

```
if (checkbox1_status == 1)
{
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(arg0, R.raw.bierflasche);
mp.start();
}
```

Comment: What is the code with which you play the sound? and do you get any error messages in logcat?

Comment: Show your code please and Logcat output if error occurs

Comment: sorry ... whre can I post the code??

Comment: if (checkbox1_status == 1)
{
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(arg0, R.raw.bierflasche);
mp.start();
}

Comment: I have added the code ...in my question

Comment: Put a debug/log line around the code that you expect to be running. Is this code inside the if statement even being run the "first time"? The debug line will check for that.